# Do RFC standards require the filename value for MIME attachment to be encapsulated in quotes?

Tags: email, email-attachments, mime

I have two conflicting sections of code.  One produces:

```
Content-Type: text/html; name=foo_foo2.blah
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo_foo2.blah
```

Another produces:

```
Content-Type: text/html; name="foo_foo2.blah"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foo_foo2.blah"
```

The one without quotes is resulting in unexpected behavior by a receiving application.  Are quotes required?

In [RFC 2183](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) I don't see an explicit requirement:

> In the extended BNF notation of [RFC 822], the Content-Disposition
>   header field is defined as follows:
>
> ```
>  disposition := "Content-Disposition" ":"
>                 disposition-type
>                 *(";" disposition-parm)
>
>  disposition-type := "inline"
>                    / "attachment"
>                    / extension-token
>                    ; values are not case-sensitive
>
>  disposition-parm := filename-parm
>                    / creation-date-parm
>                    / modification-date-parm
>                    / read-date-parm
>                    / size-parm
>                    / parameter
>
>  filename-parm := "filename" "=" value
>
>  creation-date-parm := "creation-date" "=" quoted-date-time
>
>  modification-date-parm := "modification-date" "=" quoted-date-time
>
>  read-date-parm := "read-date" "=" quoted-date-time
>
>  size-parm := "size" "=" 1*DIGIT
>
>  quoted-date-time := quoted-string
>                   ; contents MUST be an RFC 822 `date-time'
>                   ; numeric timezones (+HHMM or -HHMM) MUST be used
> ```

Perhaps I'm blind though.  Can someone please confirm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just below the BNF is this passage:

> `Extension-token', `parameter', `tspecials' and `value' are defined
>   according to [RFC 2045] (which references [RFC 822] in the definition
>   of some of these tokens).  `quoted-string' and `DIGIT' are defined in
>   [RFC 822].

2045 has this definition in section 5.1 (which however describes `Content-type:`):

```
  value := token / quoted-string

 token := 1*<any (US-ASCII) CHAR except SPACE, CTLs,
             or tspecials>

 tspecials :=  "(" / ")" / "<" / ">" / "@" /
               "," / ";" / ":" / "\" / <">
               "/" / "[" / "]" / "?" / "="
               ; Must be in quoted-string,
               ; to use within parameter values
```

So a filename which is a `token` does not need to be quoted; but if it contains any of the `tspecials` (or control characters or whitespace), you need to quote it after all.

Just to specifically address the case of underscore, it is not a character which requires quoting *according to the RFC* (it's not control, whitespace, or enumerated as one of the `tspecials`), but the way things are in the wild, you are probably better off quoting everything just in case. (Shall we call this anti-Postel? Be *unduly* conervative about what you transmit, and don't be too liberal in what you think you can infer about obviously invalid input.)

As a bit of an aside, MIME filenames in email are in practice completely the Wild West; a lot of popular applications simply ignore RFC2231 and use RFC2047 encoding here instead, or no encoding, or completely their own ad hoc "I thought this might work and nobody has complained" concoctions.

Comment: What about underscore? `_` I don't see that listed and that's in the filename (I'll update my question).

Comment: It was basically answered implicitly already but I added a passage about underscore.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not required.

rfc2183 states:

```
`Extension-token', `parameter', `tspecials' and `value' are defined
according to [RFC 2045] (which references [RFC 822] in the definition
of some of these tokens).  `quoted-string' and `DIGIT' are defined in
[RFC 822].
```

and rfc2045 defines `value` as the following:

```
value := token / quoted-string

token := 1*<any (US-ASCII) CHAR except SPACE, CTLs,
            or tspecials>

tspecials :=  "(" / ")" / "<" / ">" / "@" /
              "," / ";" / ":" / "\" / <">
              "/" / "[" / "]" / "?" / "="
              ; Must be in quoted-string,
              ; to use within parameter values
```

This means that the `filename` parameter does not need to be quoted as long as it fits within the definition of a `token`.

That said, adding quotes around the filename parameter is probably a good way of increasing compatibility with existing software. As you've discovered, not all software implements these specifications properly, often making (incorrect) assumptions about what the format is.

Comment: Dang, you were a *little* bit faster. But also slightly less precise.

Comment: I pretty much stick to MIME/email related questions and I guess I just opened my SO tab at just the right moment ;)